# Change SQL Path Of SQL Plus

Tags: sql, oracle10g

1. Can anyone let me know How to specify the SQL Path enviornment in XP?
2. How to change the dir in SQL Plus?

Many Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change directory in sqlplus on windows. However you can use the SQLPATH variable to specify the location of the sql scripts.

Refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/ch2.htm#i1133354) on oracle docs for more info on SQLPATH